# How to keep only the last X characters from all rows in a dataframe column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe column where I would like to keep only the last X characters for each row (in my case 7). The string is in the format xxxxxxx_xxxxxxx where the first and last 7 characters differ.

```
x <- data.frame("Var" = c("1970820_1970821", "1623789_1623777", "4862221_4862011", "4764567_4767067"))
```

I would like to reproduce:

```
data.frame("Var" = c("1970821", "1623777", "4862011", "4767067"))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `substr` if the need is to extract fixed number of characterss

```
x$Var <- substring(x$Var, nchar(as.character(x$Var)) - 6)
x$Var
#[1] "1970821" "1623777" "4862011" "4767067"
```

Or with `strsplit`

```
x$Var <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(x$Var), "_", fixed = TRUE), `[`, 2)
```

Or another option with `read.table`

```
x$Var <- read.table(text = as.character(x$Var), sep="_", header = FALSE)[,2]
```

or remove the characters upto `_` and have variable number of digits

```
x$Var <- sub(".*_", "", x$Var)
```

---

Or another option is `word`

```
library(stringr)
x$Var <- word(x$Var, 2, sep= "_")
```

Or another option is `str_remove`

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%
   mutate(Var = str_remove(Var, ".*_"))
```